# Powershell encode with powershell commands

Tags: powershell

I have below powershell commands,

```
$tmp = Get-Content 'C:\Users\username\Documents\emp_details.txt'
$tmp[0..75], ':tech emp details', $tmp[76.. ($tmp.Count -1)] | 
    Set-Content 'C:\Users\username\Documents\emp_details.txt'
```

which I want to encode and this entire commands as string and store it to variable and then will decode and execute it whenever I needed. But when I tried to decode using below which internally executes the Get-Content command as well.

```
$Bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes("$tmp = Get-Content 'C:\Users\username\Documents\emp_details.txt'
$tmp[0..75], ':tech emp details', $tmp[76.. ($tmp.Count -1)] | 
    Set-Content 'C:\Users\username\Documents\emp_details.txt'")
$EncodedText =[Convert]::ToBase64String($Bytes)
$EncodedText
```

Any idea please to encode those commands as strings without executing those commands internally.

Comment: Look into assigning it as a script block to a variable.

Comment: On another note, the first code block appears to be reading and writing to the same file. Has this worked well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phil's suggestion of making a script block is a good one. Here is how to store the command into a variable `$thecmd`.

```
$thecmd = {$tmp = Get-Content "C:\Users\$Env:USERNAME\Documents\$emp_details.txt"
    $tmp[0..75], ':tech emp details', $tmp[76.. ($tmp.Count -1)] | 
    Set-Content "C:\Users\$Env:USERNAME\Documents\emp_details_out.txt"}
```

The value of `$thecmd` will be the scriptblock text. In order to run it, use the invocation operator (`&`).

```
& $thecmd
```

I changed your hardcoded path to use the $Env:USERNAME variable. Also, what happens if the source text file does not have at least 75 lines?

Comment: Am pretty sure the content would be there on all file, since it was copied myself only but missed to add one line. It works perfect. But its not working when I try to encode and decode and then execute it. Below the syntax which I attempted `$readbytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($thecmd)
$ecryptString =[Convert]::ToBase64String($readbytes)
$decryptString = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($ecryptString))
& $decryptString`

Comment: Getting below error, `The term '$tmp = Get-Content "C:\Users\$Env:USERNAME\Documents\$emp_details.txt"
    $tmp[0..75], ':tech emp details', $tmp[76.. ($tmp.Count -1)] | 
    Set-Content "C:\Users\$Env:USERNAME\Documents\emp_details_out.txt"' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, func
tion, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path
 is correct and try again.`

Comment: I do not see the invocation operator before $thecmd. Please edit code into the question. It is too difficult to read in a comment.

Comment: Found the issue, When we encrypt and decrypt the ScriptBlock is converted to String type, so had to convert back to ScriptBlock to make it work, Thanks

Comment: My guess is that the invocation operator (`&) converts the string to a scriptblock. It would be helpful if you could edit the working code into the question.

Comment: It would probably be better to change `"C:\Users\$Env:USERNAME\Documents\$emp_details.txt"` to `"$Env:USERPROFILE\Documents\$emp_details.txt"`.